# Maven 3 archetypes for WAS 8 or Liberty

Tags: websphere, websphere-8, websphere-liberty

Are there any Maven archetypes for Websphere 8 and Webshpere liberty.

I just want to get started on a JAX-RS war?

Comment: I'm not a Maven expert, but I'm not aware of any.  The only Maven integration I'm aware of is documented in the InfoCenter: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_dev_maven.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some archetypes for WAS 855 and Liberty 855, but none for JAX-RS yet.

To use them, you need to add [the following repository](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/maven/repository), for example, in your settings.xml file.

To use the archetypes from RAD 9 or WDT 855, you can open the new Maven project wizard and the archetypes should be listed in the second page of the wizard, if you select the correct catalog.

Most of the archetypes include one dependency like this in the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.tools.target</groupId>
    <artifactId>was</artifactId>
    <version>8.5.5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

This dependency groups the runtime libraries. If you want to manage the runtime dependencies by yourself, you can remove the dependency above.

If you have not followed the steps described in this [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.maven.doc/topics/localrepo.html), you will find that a lot of dependencies cannot be found during the build because of the dependency mentioned above:

Note: if you are using liberty archetypes, instead of using the files listed in the step 5 of the previous link, use the files in the folder com/ibm/tools/target/was.liberty.installer in the repository mentioned previously. Download the files was.liberty.installer-8.5.0.pom or was.liberty.installer-8.5.5.pom, rename them to pom.xml, and use them in step 5. This is because the files in the repository are more current than the files shipped in RAD 9 and WDT 8.5.5.

Comment: Hopefully a JAX-RS archetype will be added soon and possible sample arquillian setup!